# PHP mySQL, how to get data from mysql for today ranging between 2 dates

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have two columns in my `MySQL` table, `valid_from` & `valid_till` both have dates in them.

I want to get the record for today's date like for example if today is 2016-04-22, and there is a record in my table which has valid_from & valid_till dates and today's date falls within the range of that record, then I want that record.

My question is how can I do that? Thank you!

The image of my table:

[image]

Comment: "between" is your friend

Comment: As @gavgrif mentioned, or the <= and >= operators. Just refer to the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html

Comment: Additionally ensure your columns are of the correct type - DATETIME or a UNIX timestamp would suffice.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your valueable comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way you test if the date, for example today's date, id between *valid_from* date and *valid_till* date:

```
select * from (table_name) 
where (date_to_test) > valid_from and (date_to_test) < valid_till;
```

Comment: What's with the parentheses?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your valueable comments guys. i got it to working with the query:

```
SELECT * FROM `exchangerate` WHERE '$DateToday' between `valid_from` and `valid_till`
```